# Selecting an option element from a dropdown by its text value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Given an HTML form element like:

```
<select id='mydropdown'>
  <option value='foo'>Spam</option>
  <option value='bar'>Eggs</option>
</select>
```

I know I can select the first option with

```
document.getElementById("mydropdown").value='foo'
```

However, say I have a variable with the value "Spam"; can I select a dropdown item by its text rather than by its value?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var desiredValue = "eggs"
var el = document.getElementById("mydropdown");
for(var i=0; i<el.options.length; i++) {
  if ( el.options[i].text == desiredValue ) {
    el.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < ddlc.options.length; i++) {

                                if (jQuery.trim(ddlc.options[i].text) == jQuery.trim(result)) {
                                    alert("Entered the needed");
                                    var insertedtimeid = i
                                    $("#ddlCategory").val(insertedtimeid).trigger('updated').trigger('change');
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the selectedIndex or a loop to select the option by text, the code below doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById("mydropdown").text = 'Eggs';
```

Comment: I don't want the text of the currently selected value; I want to set the value based on the text. Looping through `el.options` and looking for the right `.text` attribute looks promising, though.

Comment: yeah I think that's your best bet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an option by its innertext and not by the value you can do this:

```
function go(){
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('mydropdown');
    var textSelected = 'Spam';

    for(var i=0, max=dropdown.children.length; i<max; i++) {
        if(textSelected == dropdown.children[i].innerHTML){
            alert(textSelected);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason you're using the children collection vs. dropdown.options and dropdown.options[i].text?

Comment: There is no specific reason, I just wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

Older IE does not handle options of a select as child nodes, but all browsers implement the **text** property of a select's option collection.

```
function selectbytext(sel, txt){
    if(typeof sel== 'string'){
        sel= document.getELementById(sel) || document.getELementsByName(sel)[0];
    }
    var opts= sel.options;
    for(var i= 0, L= opts.length; i<L; i++){
        if(opts[i].text== txt){
            sel.selectedIndex= i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```